# Does gettimeofday() on macOS use a system call?

Tags: c, macos, time, operating-system, system-calls

I expect that `gettimeofday()` will call a system call to do the work of actually getting the time. However, running the following program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct timeval tv;

    printf("Before gettimeofday() %ld!\n", tv.tv_sec);

    int rc = gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    printf("After gettimeofday() %ld\n", tv.tv_sec);

    if (rc == -1) {
        printf("Error: gettimeofday() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Exiting ! %ld\n", tv.tv_sec);
    return 0;
}
```

under `dtruss -d` returns a long list of system calls, the last of which are:

```
RELATIVE SYSCALL(args)           = return

... lots of syscalls with earlier timestamps ...

    3866 fstat64(0x1, 0x7FFF56ABC8D8, 0x11)      = 0 0
    3868 ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFF56ABC91C)      = 0 0
    3882 write_nocancel(0x1, "Before gettimeofday() 0!\n\0", 0x19)       = 25 0
    3886 write_nocancel(0x1, "After gettimeofday() 1480913810\n\0", 0x20)        = 32 0
    3887 write_nocancel(0x1, "Exiting ! 1480913810\n\0", 0x15)       = 21 0
```

It looks like `gettimeofday()` isn't using a syscall, but this seems wrong-surely the kernel takes responsibility of the system clocks? Is `dtruss` missing something? Am I reading the output incorrectly?

Comment: On Solaris, `gettimeofday()` simply reads a memory location.  It may well be that there is something similar going on with macOS Sierra (or the prior Mac OS X versions).  You might or might not be interested to note that macOS Sierra (but not earlier versions) supports `clock_gettime()` at long last.

Comment: You can see the `gettimeofday()` system call in the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.1.32/bsd/kern/syscalls.master.auto.html) - #116

Comment: On Linux, a system call such as `gettimeofday()` may be implemented as a *"normal function call and a few memory accesses"*: [vDSO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As TheDarkKnight [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967594/does-gettimeofday-on-macos-use-a-system-call#comment69152018_40967594), there is a `gettimeofday` system call. However, the userspace `gettimeofday` function often does **not** call the corresponding system call, but rather `__commpage_gettimeofday`, which tries to read the time from a special part of the process' address space called the *commpage*. Only if this call fails does the `gettimeofday` system call get used as a fallback. This reduces the cost of most calls to `gettimeofday` from that of an ordinary system call to just a memory read.

The book [Mac OSX Internals: A Systems Approach](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=K8vUkpOXhN4C&pg=PA594&lpg=PA594&dq=mac+os+commpage&hl=en#v=onepage&q=mac%20os%20commpage&f=false) describes the commpage. Briefly, it is a special area of kernel memory that is mapped into the last eight pages of the address space of every process. Among other things, it contains time values that are "updated asynchronously from the kernel and read atomically from user space, leading to occasional failures in reading".

To see how often the `gettimeofday()` system call is called by the userspace function, I wrote a test program that called `gettimeofday()` 100 million times in a tight loop:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    const int NUM_TRIALS = 100000000;
    struct timeval tv;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIALS; i++) {
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running this under `dtruss -d` on my machine showed that this triggered between 10-20 calls to the `gettimeofday()` system calls (0.00001%-0.00002% of all the userspace calls).

---

For those interested, the relevant lines in the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1082.50.1/sys/gettimeofday.c.auto.html) for the userspace `gettimeofday()` function (for macOS 10.11 - El Capitan) are

```
if (__commpage_gettimeofday(tp)) {      /* first try commpage */
    if (__gettimeofday(tp, NULL) < 0) { /* if it fails, use syscall */
        return (-1);
    }
}
```

The function `__commpage_gettimeofday` [combines](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/10.11/libsyscall/wrappers/__commpage_gettimeofday.s#L99-L102) the timestamp read from the commpage and a reading of the time stamp counter register to calculate the time since epoch in seconds and microseconds. (The `rdstc` instruction is inside [`_mach_absolute_time`](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/10.11/libsyscall/wrappers/mach_absolute_time.s#L128).)

Comment: Very interesting.  Thank you.

Comment: Good answer. You mention: _This reduces the cost of most calls to gettimeofday from that of an ordinary system call to just a memory read._ This doesn't seem strictly true: the `___commpage_gettimeofday` and `_mach_absolute_time` functions (with the former calling the latter) are a couple dozen instructions each, with perhaps 10 total memory reads between them, and the `rdtsc` call itself is two dozen cycles or more (plus they have two `lfence` instructions in there for some reason). So probably you are looking at at least 50 cycles. Still much better than a kernel call!

Answer (score 1):

The use of dtrace instead of dtruss will clear your doubt. 
gettimeofday() is itself a system call. You can see this system call getting called if you run dtrace script.

You can use following dtrace script 
"dtrace1.d"

```
syscall:::entry
/ execname == "foo" / 
{
}
```

(foo is the name of your executable)

to run above dtrace use: dtrace -s dtrace1.d

and then execute your program to see all system call used by your program

Comment: I've followed your instructions and `dtrace` does not identify a `gettimeofday` system call. Its output is almost identical to `dtruss`, and apart from listing the call to `exit()` at the very end of the program, the last five system calls (see the question) are the same. I'm running El Capitan (10.11.6). Do you see something different on your computer?