# How C `time()` function gets the current system time?

Tags: c

I know that I can get the current local time by `time()` function in C.

```
int main(void)
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&now);
}
```

However, I want to the insider of the `time()` function, which means I want to know how the function knows the system time.

In, `time.h` file, I see that there is defined of the function and it looks like the one below.

```
time_t time(time_t *);
```

Thus, I find what `time_t` is and it is defined like the one below.

```
typedef __darwin_time_t         time_t;
```

Finally, `__darwin_time_t` type is defined like the one below.

```
typedef long                    __darwin_time_t;
```

How the `time()` function get the current time? Where the code to get the current time of the system?

I'm a beginner of the C programming and wonder how the compiler gets the time.

Comment: That depends on the underlying platform (OS and/or HW). The C language standard does not dictate how time-related functionality should be implemented internally under the hood. In most platforms, this function probably makes a low-level system call, to the OS kernel. That is, if there's even an OS to begin with. If not, it may access the HW clock or similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does gettimeofday() on macOS use a system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967594/does-gettimeofday-on-macos-use-a-system-call)

Answer (score 1):

Q: I want to know how the function knows the system time.

A: bbbbbbbbb is correct:

> That depends on the underlying platform (OS and/or HW). The C language
> standard does not dictate how time-related functionality should be
> implemented internally under the hood. In most platforms, this
> function probably makes a low-level system call, to the OS kernel.
> That is, if there's even an OS to begin with. If not, they may access
> the HW clock or similar.

More specifically:

- Associated with every different C compiler (MS Visual C++, Gnu C/C++, Apache CLang, etc. etc.) for every different platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, embedded system, etc. etc.) is a [C runtime library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2766233/421195) ("CRT").
- Source code for your particular CRT is often freely available (e.g. from a Google search).
- If you can find a copy of the C runtime source ... you can see how any given standard C function is implemented (at least for your particular compiler/OS/platform).

Since you're apparently on a Mac, I did a Google search of "time.c opensource.apple.com":

- Standard C time functions:  https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/ctime.c.auto.html
- "time" shell command: https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-216.60.1/time/time.c.auto.html