# Microbenchmarking C code and cache effects

Tags: c, performance, performance-testing, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm on macOS Sonoma using an M1 Pro, using `clang` 15 (`clang-1500.0.40.1`) without any (explicit) optimization when I compile. *(EDIT: With -O3 there are no meaningful differences I can observe between the various versions. The last version seems to be slightly faster compared to previous runs of the same version, though.)*

I wrote a small function to shuffle an array and I would like to test its performance. In order to do so, I wrote the following function:

```
void test_performance() {
    // initialize only once to measure performance
    int ns[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int ops = 1E6;
    int start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < ops; i++) {
        shuffle(ns, 5);
    }
    int end = clock();
    double s_total = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    double ns_op = s_total / ops * 1E9;
    printf("test_performance: %fns/op (%fs total) \n", ns_op, s_total);
}
```

On my machine, this yields ~30ns/op.

I then realized that the looping operations were included in the measurements. I though it was probably close to negligible, but that I could have got rid of that small noise, so I changed it to call `clock()` within the loop and add the *actual* time spent on `shuffle` to an accumulator, resulting in the following code.

```
void test_performance() {
    // initialize only once to measure performance
    int ns[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int ops = 1E6;
    int start, end, ticks = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ops; i++) {
        start = clock();
        shuffle(ns, 5);
        end = clock();
        ticks += (end - start);
    }
    double s_total = ((double) ticks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    double ns_op = s_total / ops * 1E9;
    printf("test_performance: %fns/op (%fs total) \n", ns_op, s_total);
}
```

The program overall ran visibly slower, which is not that surprising, given that now I have a couple million more calls to `clock()`. What I did find surprising, however, is that the time per operation reported at the end increased by an order-of-magnitude, around ~330ns/op.

First question: what could cause this massive difference?

My best guess is that his has to do with modern hardware, caching and the fact that `clock()` possibly involves a system call, with the code for `shuffle` being always in a CPU cache in one case and being constantly evicted in the other, but I'm not really sure whether that's the case or if there's something more obvious I'm missing.

Second question: if that's the case, what are good practices when using C to do microbenchmarking and evaluate the impact of caching? I'm interested primarily in making relatively robust benchmarks without requiring specialized tooling, but I'd also be happy to hear about microbenchmarking tools used by the C community.

#### EDIT

Interestingly, I tried to use `clock_gettime`, which also allows to explicitly ask for time which is monotonically increasing, ending up with the following:

```
void test_performance() {
    struct timespec start_time, end_time;
    // initialize only once to measure performance
    int ns[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int ops = 1E6;
    double s_total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ops; i++) {
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_time) != 0) {
            perror("clock_gettime");
            return;
        }
        shuffle(ns, 5);
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end_time) != 0) {
            perror("clock_gettime");
            return;
        }
        s_total += (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) + (end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec) / 1.0e9;
    }
    double ns_op = s_total / ops * 1E9;
    printf("test_performance: %fns/op (%fs total) \n", ns_op, s_total);
}
```

Interestingly, this code reported times around ~25ns. When I tried to put the time measurements *around* the whole loop instead of measuring individual calls, the times reported went back to ~30ns as in my first experiment using `clock()`.

I'd love to understand why `clock_gettime` doesn't seem to cause the same penalty as `clock()`.

Comment: I often use a hot loop for a warm-up then count rdtsc cycles as the cost of these is very low.

Comment: "With -O3 there are no meaningful differences I can observe between the various versions." Measuring how fast your car is by walking behind it and pushing it manually isn't going to be helpful, that's for sure. Always benchmark with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Anyway, I suppose it depends a whole lot on how `shuffle` is implemented and what happens when the compiler first potentially inlines it, then optimizes further from there. A plain loop with no other side effects gives the compiler more freedom to do all manner of tricks.

Comment: And finally, nanosecond accuracy doesn't really exist on some PC. You might be fooling yourself if you think that. If some context switch decides to saunter in during your benchmark test, then what? All timing gets tossed out the window.

Comment: You definitely want a repeat loop to be *inside* the timed region to amortize timing overhead.  Some loop unrolling can amortize the repeat-loop cost if you think it might be non-trivial, but taking timestamps between every invocation of the code under test is disastrous.  (`rdtsc` on modern x86 only takes about 20 clock cycles, but `lfence; rdtsc` or `rdtscp` to drain the ROB (reorder buffer) preventing out-of-order exec of `rdtsc` takes more.  And so does scaling the result into a nanosecond timestamp.)  See also [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)

Comment: @SimonGoater What is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your machine?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't know what you mean with CLOCKS_PER_SEC. Is that some macro? As far as rdtsc cycles are concerned, I think my machine counts as if the CPU is using it's max frequency (GHz) whether it is or not, so it's important to do a warmup. One time I measured a sleep(1) and it gave me the 2.67 billion which is the frequency of my old laptop CPU. I usually just use the cycles as a relative measure for performance optimisation rather than trying to convert it to seconds.

Comment: @Simon Goater, Sorry, My question was to the wrong <S> user.

Comment: @stefanobaghino, What is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your machine?  (As used in `((double) ticks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC`)

Answer (score 2):

> First question: what could cause this massive difference?

Hard to tell because benchmarking stuff with optimizations disabled makes little-to-no sense, you will have to take a look at the generated machine code to understand things better.

Performing a system call and breaking the loop two times per iteration means executing a lot of useless instructions that you don't really want to time, which can easily trash the processor pipeline, and therefore decrease performance by a lot. A compiler might or might not be able to order instructions in an optimized way to avoid this. In your case it probably didn't (makes sense since you are telling it you don't care about optimizations).

It could also cause more rescheduling by the OS because syscall entry/exit are usually common scheduler entry points where your task can be set a side for others to run, without the need of kernel preemption happening (like if you do a tight userspace loop with no syscalls).

> I'd love to understand why `clock_gettime` doesn't seem to cause the same penalty as `clock()`.

See the answer here: [Does gettimeofday() on macOS use a system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40988008/3889449)

`clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` is likely just a wrapper around `gettimeofday`, which takes a fast path via userspace and does not need a context switch (most of the times). This is a common optimization for simple and frequently used syscalls.

I don't know much about how macOS implements its "commpage" used to perform some common syscalls without context switch, but I suppose it's pretty similar to how Linux implements the "[vDSO](https://manned.org/vdso.7)".

Comment: I think you have it backwards: `gettimeofday` is obsolete (according to POSIX) and often just a wrapper around `clock_gettime` that divides nanoseconds by 1000 to get microseconds.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not sure, code [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1158.1.2/gen/clock_gettime.c.auto.html) seems to suggest the opposite: `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` -> `_mach_boottime_usec()` -> [`gettimeofday()`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1082.50.1/sys/gettimeofday.c.auto.html) -> `__commpage_gettimeofday()` OR syscall.

Comment: Oh weird.  Linux does it the other way since `clock_gettime` is the more general function, and uses the nanosecond precision `struct timespec` that the Linux kernel uses internally.  Your answer somewhat implies that Linux does it "backwards" as well, which I'm pretty sure is not the case.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah that *is* weird. I am also pretty sure Linux does the opposite, [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/gettimeofday.c#L63) (well on Linux `clock_gettime` is also an actual syscall). Will update the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: IIRC, last time I single-stepped into Linux's `gettimdeofday`, the vDSO code for it did eventually end up dividing something by 1000 with an `imul` and shift.  Probably after calling into the `clock_gettime` vDSO code, but my memory is a little fuzzy on that.

Comment: @PeterCordes just to clarify my last comment I mean that I am pretty sure Linux implements `gettimeofday` as wrapper of `clock_gettime`, but when I say that I am talking about libc implementing the `gettimeofday` library function as a wrapper around the `clock_gettime` syscall, not the kernel itself. I think they are still different code paths in the kernel, vDSO or not, it's just the underlying "clock" they end up querying that is the same. [This](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/lib/vdso/gettimeofday.c#L310) is probably what you saw in vDSO.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh found it, [here it is](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/lib/vdso/gettimeofday.c#L307) the fallback of `gettimeofday` in vDSO doing a `syscall` for `clock_gettime` in case it fails the fast path. So you are right, even in kernel code there is a fallback to `clock_gettime`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibility: truncated clock measurement and/or `int` overflow.

`int start = clock();` may truncate the measurement if `clock_t` is wider than `int`.  As the 2nd code does many more measurements that the 1st, the odds of a pair of readings (one truncated, the other not) increase the chance of a calculation error in doing the difference.

Also the difference and summation may overflow.  Use a wide type.

Use:

```
long long ticks = 0;
...
  clock_t start = clock();
  ...
  clock_t end = clock();
  ticks += (long long) end - start;
...
```

Comment: It turns out this is not the case, but I still learned something new, thank you!